# How can I prove that $(A, \circ )$ make a group, where $A = \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$, $a \circ b := \frac{(ab)}{3}$?

Tags: group-theory

$A = \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$, $a \circ b := \frac{(ab)}{3}$

I know that: associativity, inverse, identity element.

$(a \circ b) \circ c = \frac{ab}{3} \circ c $ but I don't know how to continue with that. Can you help me?

The identity element is $3$, the inverse is $9/a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget **closure**! Here $(A,\circ)$ is closed since, for any $a,b\in A$, we have $a\circ b=\frac{ab}{3}\neq 0$ since $a,b\neq 0$. (Think about the contrapositive . . . )

**Associativity** follows from that of multiplication. Explicitly: for all $a,b,c\in A$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(a\circ b)\circ c&=\left(\frac{ab}{3}\right)\circ c\\
&=\cfrac{\cfrac{ab}{3}c}{3}\\
&=\cfrac{\cfrac{(ab)c}{3}}{3}\\
&=\cfrac{\cfrac{a(bc)}{3}}{3}\\
&=\cfrac{a\cfrac{bc}{3}}{3}\\
&=a\circ\left(\frac{bc}{3}\right)\\
&=a\circ (b\circ c).
\end{align}$$

The **identity** is indeed $3$.

The **inverse** of $a$ is indeed $9/a$, which can be checked by direct computation:

$$\begin{align}
a\circ(9/a)&=\frac{a(9/a)}{3}\\
&=\frac{9}{3}\\
&=3.
\end{align}$$

Comment: But I don't know how to continue with ab/3 ∘ c. So is it ( (ab/3*c) / (ab/3+c) )?

Comment: Please hold on while I edit in some more details, @avon016g.

Comment: Is that better, @avon016g?

Comment: absolutely yes, I understand and thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, @avon016g.

Comment: Why do people answer homework like this with a full solution?

Comment: I believe the OP provided sufficient context, @pindakaas.